Daily deltas implementation
We have a feed of json lines files from a vendor.  The whole corpus is about 45-50M records.  They send us daily updates.
The old implementation has a heap with a couple of indexes to hold the corpus, and then a daily delta table the json lines file is loaded into.  When the system is up and running, there would be maybe 10,000 deltas in a day.
The process was to load the json into the delta table, fish the vendor id out of the json, delete the master table record and then insert all the new daily rows.
Recently the vendor changed their json structure and we're having to reload a new base set into essentially the same system.
I figured 45 million rows is a lot to move in one batch, but shouldn't be insurmountable, but it's taking an inordinate amount of time and I'm running out of optimizations to attempt.
It's a vm in the Google Cloud Platform, running Sql Server 2019 with 256 gig of ram and 32 cpus.  The database is in Simple mode.
We got the load to the delta table pretty fast by fishing the vendor id out in C# and inserting it into a new column and then multithreading the SqlBulkCopy operations to an indexless heap, but getting 45 m rows from the delta table to the master table is taking forever.
My first thought was to try and get the inserts done in batches to keep the transaction overhead low, so I tried something like this:
declare @handle int = 0, @cursorRC int, @batchSize int = 20000, @rowcount int, @last bit = 0, @totalRowcount int = 0;
BEGIN TRY
exec sp_cursoropen @handle output,'select vendorid, json from dbo.vwLOAD', @scrollopt=16, @ccopt=1 -- open cursor
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO MasterTable (vendorid, RAWJSON)
        exec sp_cursorfetch @handle, 2,  0, @batchSize
    SET @cursorRc = @@ROWCOUNT
    IF (@cursorRc < @batchSize) SET @last = 1;

    SET @totalRowCount += @cursorRC

    IF @cursorRC = 0 OR @last = 1 BREAK
END
exec sp_cursorclose @handle
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
    IF (@handle > 0)
    BEGIN
        exec sp_cursorclose @handle
    END
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000) = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @ErrorSeverity INT = ERROR_SEVERITY(), @ErrorState INT = ERROR_STATE();  
    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage,  @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState)
END CATCH

Move the rows over in 20K chunks with a big batch cursor.  I tried it twice, and both times it crapped out with an obtuse error after 11 hours ("A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.").
And it was really slow.  Watching Task Monitor, the ram was at 80%, cpu at 2%, some read disk i/o but very little write i/o.  If it hadn't crapped out it looked like it would take 75 hours to move 45 million rows.
I got frustrated and just started a single statement to do it.  It's been running 3 hours so far.  I'm not sure how far along it is, but I'm seeing 15-20mb/s R and 28mb/s W pretty consistently.  Pretty low but still well above what the batch above was doing.
The insert statement was just a vanilla
INSERT INTO MasterTable (vendorID, RAWJSON)
select vendorid, json from dbo.vwLOAD

It ran 5.5 hours and eventually the log file at up all the disk space so the transaction died.
Are there any good tips for a master/delta merge implementation like this?
The master table looks a lot like the delta table, only with an index on the vendorid and an index on a rowversion column to tell when things change.
There's not a lot to the tables.  The json blobs average 67k each.  We just had the C# loader fetch the vendor id out and put it in a separate column because we're getting much better throughput with the file streaming that way.  It's the table to table transfer that's taking forever.
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MasterTable](
    [VendorID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RAWJSON] [nvarchar](max) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8 NOT NULL,
    [Changed] [timestamp] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Changed] ON [dbo].[MasterTable]
(
    [Changed] ASC
)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NonClusteredIndex-20231010-235246] ON [dbo].[MasterTable]
(
    [VendorID] ASC
)

CREATE TABLE LoadDB_Delta(
    [JsonBlob] [nvarchar](max) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8 NOT NULL,
    [SourceFileName]  [nvarchar](500) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8 NOT NULL,
    [VendorID] [int] NOT NULL
)

This is the output of the sp_spaceused sproc on the load table:
[name]          rows                    reserved        data            index_size
LoadDB_Delta    45780028                1500939408 KB   1500917248 KB   2952 KB 19208 KB

EDIT: As was pointed out, I didn't include the definition of vwLOAD.  Now, this was one of the inherited bit.  I discovered the REPLACE function for snipping one member (why I still don't know) was a huge delay.  But it still ran a crazy long time even when that was removed.
As was also suggested, we did switch from NVARCHAR to utf8 varchar for the space.
The run with the view below took 80.5 hours to copy the 1.5 tb/45 m records.  With the REPLACE removed, it still took 12.5 hours for the same copy.  That still seems like an inordinately long time to copy 45 m rows from one table to another.
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwLoad]
AS
SELECT VendorID
      ,Replace([JsonBlob],'"type":"NEW",','') JSON
FROM [dbo].[LoadDB] delta
GO


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Bulk load performance
In general, you will need to achieve minimally logged bulk load to match the speed of an optimized insert from a file source.
The full set of conditions is somewhat complex, but in its most basic form the empty target heap table should have no nonclustered indexes and a TABLOCK hint:
INSERT dbo.MasterTable
    WITH (TABLOCK) -- Important!
    (vendorID, RAWJSON)
SELECT VendorID, JsonBlob
FROM dbo.LoadDB_Delta;

Be sure to drop the nonclustered indexes first. People usually add nonclustered indexes back after the bulk load is complete. Building the indexes will usually be a parallel and minimally logged operation, which is much more efficient than maintaining secondary indexes row by row during the load.
If you still observe slow performance, please add an estimated (pre-execution) plan to your question.
Space usage
As a side note, you're currently using twice as much storage as necessary for the json. The nvarchar(max) column is using UTF-16. If you want UTF-8, use varchar(max) with the same UTF8 collation. See UTF-8 support in the documentation.

It's a shame the two tables have different schemas (columns in a different order, extra rowversion column). Otherwise, you could have used a metadata SWITCH, which is instant.
Related reading:

The Data Loading Performance Guide by Microsoft
Minimal Logging with INSERT…SELECT into Heap Tables by me
Minimal Logging with INSERT…SELECT and Fast Load Context by me

